# Facebook Like Button Content Locker on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, facebook-like

I've been pulling my hair out trying to figure this out. Hopefully someone can help please.

I'm trying to content lock this site: blog.funnyhunt.com

The idea is that people are supposed to like my facebook page when someone clicks the like button (which works fine) and then the content is revealed... but that last bit does not work.

Now heres the weird part... for some people it works fine, and for others it won't reveal the content it just lets them like the page and the content stays locked.

I've tested this with a range of different like lockers and I keep getting the same experience, some times it works, other times not.

So what is going on?? I've tried testing it with different facebook accounts, proxies, and clearing cookies... but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the following plugin: http://codecanyon.net/item/like-2-unlock-for-wordpress/2858703?ref=onepress

Answer (score 0):

I have developed a content locker in JavaScript with the following features:

- SEO (Search Engine Optimization): since we want search engines to be
  able to read the contents and index them, we'll just hide them.
- Standard social widgets: we'll add these content locking features to
  the Facebook, Twitter, Google+ and LinkedIn  native source code.
- Soft behavior: since we do not want to disturb our loyal readers,
  once the content is unlocked, unlocking will affect all blocked
  contents on the web site.
- The source code is JavaScript, so it is possible to integrate it on
  every web page (we'll use jQuery only for visual effects).

The implementation is similar to the one of tool cited above, that is using cookies.

Here's the code, if you want to see it in action or it's integration with more social widgets, visit
[How to dramatically increase social media LIKEs to your web site](http://www.idea-r.it/Blog.aspx/increase-social-media-likes)

```
<head>
     <script src="contentslocker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
     ...
     <div class="irBodyLocker">
         <p>The rest of the article is locked</p>
         <p>To continue reading, become our friend pressing one of the buttons</p>

         ...put here the social widgets

     </div>
     <div class="irLockedBody" style="display:none;">

         ...put here the locked contents

     </div>
 </body>

The IdeaR.ContentsLocker.lockContents function is invoked by the script.

IdeaR.ContentsLocker.lockContents = function ()
 {
     $(function ()
     {
         if (IdeaR.ContentsLocker.socialActivity() == true)
         {
             $('div.irBodyLocker').hide();
             $('div.irLockedBody').show();
         }
         // Add social handlers only if contents are locked
         else
             $(function ()
             {
                 // Facebook
                 var exsistingFbAsyncInit = window.fbAsyncInit;
                 if (exsistingFbAsyncInit == null)
                     window.fbAsyncInit = 
                         IdeaR.ContentsLocker._subscribeFacebookLike();
                 else
                     window.fbAsyncInit = function ()
                     {
                         exsistingFbAsyncInit();
                         IdeaR.ContentsLocker._subscribeFacebookLike();
                     };

                 // Twitter
                 twttr.ready(function (twttr)
                 {
                     twttr.events.bind('tweet', 
                         IdeaR.ContentsLocker.ontwitteraction);
                     twttr.events.bind('follow', 
                         IdeaR.ContentsLocker.ontwitteraction);
                 });
             });
     });
 };

 IdeaR.ContentsLocker.socialActivity = function ()
 {
     return IdeaR.ContentsLocker._getCookie(
         IdeaR.ContentsLocker._socialAction, 'false') == 'true' ? true : false;
 };

 IdeaR.ContentsLocker._getCookie = function (name, defaultValue)
 {
     var docCookies = document.cookie.split(";");
     for (var i = 0; i < docCookies.length; i++)
     {
         var equalPos = docCookies[i].indexOf('=');
         var currentName = unescape(docCookies[i].substr(0, equalPos));
         currentName = currentName.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
         if (currentName == name)
         {
             var value = docCookies[i].substr(equalPos + 1);
             return unescape(value);
         }
     }
     return defaultValue;
 };

 IdeaR.ContentsLocker._socialAction = 'SocialAction';

 IdeaR.ContentsLocker._subscribeFacebookLike = function ()
 {
     FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function (targetUrl)
     {
         IdeaR.ContentsLocker.unlockContents();
     });
 };

 IdeaR.ContentsLocker.ontwitteraction = function (intent_event)
 {
     if (intent_event)
         IdeaR.ContentsLocker.unlockContents();
 };

IdeaR.ContentsLocker.unlockContents = function ()
 {
     $('div.irBodyLocker').slideUp(400, function ()
     {
         $('div.irLockedBody').fadeIn();
     });
     IdeaR.ContentsLocker.saveSocialAction();
 };

 IdeaR.ContentsLocker.saveSocialAction = function ()
 {
     IdeaR.ContentsLocker._setCookie(
         IdeaR.ContentsLocker._socialAction, true, 10000);
 };

 IdeaR.ContentsLocker._setCookie = function (name, value, expirationDays)
 {
     var cookieString = escape(name) + '=' + escape(value);
     if (expirationDays != null)
     {
         var expirationDate = new Date();
         expirationDate.setDate(expirationDate.getDate() + expirationDays);
         cookieString += '; expires=' + expirationDate.toUTCString();
     }
     document.cookie = cookieString;
 };
```